# How to inject username and password stored in vault to use in jenkinsfile (pipeline as a code)?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have my username and password stored in Vault server. While using jenkins pipeline I want to use those credentials in my jenkinspipeline file to run adn ansible play that will use those credentials on the target machine to log in and perform tasks. How can i do that in jenkinsfile ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I could figure out... the official documentation itself is wrong.

Correct usage is described here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45685